# Example of a complex compound tikz math statement

Tags: tikz-pgf, math-operators

Could someone provide an example of a complex compound mathematical statement in tikz as I find that most of the answers out there are difficult to understand or lacking. I want a MWE example like this one (note, this one does **not** compile)

```
\documentclass[landscape]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage[active,tightpage]{preview}
\PreviewEnvironment{tikzpicture}
\setlength\PreviewBorder{5pt}%

\newcommand{\tableXOff}{0.4}
\newcommand{\tableXPad}{\tableXOff}
\newcommand{\tableYOff}{0.1}
\newcommand{\tableYPad}{\tableYOff}
\newcommand{\tableW}{0.5}
\newcommand{\tableH}{0.2}
\newcommand{\xShift}{2}

\usepackage[top=1in,bottom=1in,right=1in,left=1in]{geometry}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=5.3,cap=round,>=latex]
   \draw[blue,ultra thick] (-2cm,-2cm) rectangle (2cm,2cm);
   \foreach \x in {0,1,...,3} {%
      \fill[brown] (\x*(\tableXPad+\tableW)+\tableXOff-\xShift,-\tableYOff) rectangle (\x*0.9+\tableXOff+\tableW-\xShift,-\tableYOff-\tableH);
   }
   \end{tikzpicture}
   \end{document}
```

So I don't go blind trying to read values, but instead use variables. Unfortunately, the parantheses around `(\tableXPad+\tableW)` cause an error. How do I get around this?

Comment: Put braces around (I think) the first entry in the problematic ordered pair.

Comment: @CharlesStaats please include an answer with an example as the very first thing I did was bullet riddle the statement with curly brackets

Answer (score 3):

Put braces around the entry in the ordered pair that contains the problematic parentheses:

```
\documentclass[margin=10pt,convert]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand{\tableXOff}{0.4}
\newcommand{\tableXPad}{\tableXOff}
\newcommand{\tableYOff}{0.1}
\newcommand{\tableYPad}{\tableYOff}
\newcommand{\tableW}{0.5}
\newcommand{\tableH}{0.2}
\newcommand{\xShift}{2}

\usepackage[top=1in,bottom=1in,right=1in,left=1in]{geometry}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=5.3,cap=round,>=latex]
   \draw[blue,ultra thick] (-2cm,-2cm) rectangle (2cm,2cm);
   \foreach \x in {0,1,...,3} {%
      \fill[brown] ({\x*(\tableXPad+\tableW)+\tableXOff-\xShift},-\tableYOff) rectangle (\x*0.9+\tableXOff+\tableW-\xShift,-\tableYOff-\tableH);
   }
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The result:

[image]

Comment: Sorry.  I didn't see your answer when I posted mine.

Comment: Actually, I think our posted answers were essentially simultaneous.